# How to get a value from the input and add to the href jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to do something like the window of favorites on google chrome so the idea is write a hiperlink and then the link appears on the page.I m using jquery but doesn't work

html:

```
<div id="Add" title="Add Link">
<form>
     <fieldset>
        <label for="dir">URL</label>
                  <input id="dir" type="url" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
<div id="cuadro"></div>

$(function(){
  var a = $("#Add");
  a.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height:350,
    width:250,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Accept": function(){ //Accept
            AddLink();
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Reset": function(){//Reset
            dir.val(" ")
        },
        "Cancel": function() {//Cancel
            $( this ).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  });
});

function AddLink(){
  var dir=$("#dir);
  var link=dir.val();
  alert(dir.val());
  $("#cuadro").append('<li><a href="link">link1</a></li>');
}
```

Comment: can you supply a jsfiddle?

Comment: Is `$("#direction")` supposed to be `$("#dir")`?

Comment: yes, it is, it´s for call the value of the input

Comment: Right, but your input id is "dir" not "direction".

Comment: I change that but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your `link`variable as the href then you need to change

```
$("#cuadro").append('<li><a href="link">link1</a></li>');
```

to

```
$("#cuadro").append('<li><a href="' + link + '">link1</a></li>');
```

Comment: Thank you that s what I want

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AVYD8/)**

I'm not sure exactly what you meant by "write a hiperlink and then the link appears on the page", so I'm going to do my best and guess that this is what you want:

1. User types a URL into the input box.
2. You display it in some div below it.

HTML

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="dir">URL</label>
        <input id="dir" type="url" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<p></p>
```

CSS

```
p {
    color: green;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$( "#dir" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "p" ).text( value );
  })
  .keyup();
```